# CSS: Nested backdrop-filter blur - How to do it right?

Tags: css, filter, z-index, blur

My goal is to have boxes with a blur-glass effect. To do this I use:

```css
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
```

Additionally on certain events I want to blur the whole page, except for one element (let's call it *element-x*). For the overlay I use:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  z-index: 5999;
}
```

I'm able to create the blur-glass effect. And I'm also able to make a blur-overlay.

But as soon as the *element-x* lies within the box (nested) with the blurred-glass effect. It gets blurred with the overlay.

When I remove `backdrop-filter: blur(7px);` from the box, it works.

I know it's a stacking order problem (`z-index`). But I can't get it to work, as expected. **How can I solve this problem?**

---

OK. I build a codepen for you to reproduce (use Google Chrome):
https://codepen.io/54mu3l/pen/JjNdBwd

On the top you'll find the solution that is not working.
On the bottom you'll find the expected behaviour (but without the glassed-blurred-box).

As you can see the top box has a blurred background. The bottom box hasn't:
[image]

As soon as the overlay is activated (just click anywhere on the screen). The orange box on the top gets blurred (but shouldn't). The orange box at the bottom is not blurred:
[image]

---

EDIT:
useful links:

- [CSS: backdrop-filter messing up stacking order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311979/css-backdrop-filter-messing-up-stacking-order)
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements
- http://jsfiddle.net/A2xht/

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicate, backdrop-filter create a stacking context so the box can no more go above the overlay alone, either the whole container or not

Comment: I'm aware that there are similar questions out there. And I'm aware that it has to do with the stacking order. But still I don't know how to solve this. What can I do to get the required result?

Comment: you cannot, your only way is to move the element outside the container where you apply the backdrop. If you cannot then there is no way

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If this is not possible in CSS. Do you have a workaround? Because I can't place it outside of the container. If I place it outside of the container, then I need to position it absolute with JavaScript. This is OK as long as I can calculate the exact position. But since the elements above on the page are animated (variable height) it's no longer possible to calculate the position with JS.

Comment: consider a pseudo element where you apply the filter (I will get you a related question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954144/8620333

Comment: all else aside, this is an excellent question once it has been edited, keep it up samuels